# Poll and Select weird behaviour on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, sockets, c++11

I found out an interesting thing about poll on OS X. Let me illustrate this here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <set>
#include <poll.h>


#define POLL_SIZE 32

int set_nonblock(int fd) {
  int flags;

  if(-1 == (flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0))) {
    flags = 0;
  }

  return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
}

int main() {

  int master_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

  std::set<int> slave_sockets;

  struct sockaddr_in SockAddr;
  SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  SockAddr.sin_port = htons(12345);
  SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

  bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr));

  set_nonblock(master_socket);

  listen(master_socket, SOMAXCONN);

  struct pollfd set[POLL_SIZE];
  set[0].fd = master_socket;
  set[0].events = POLL_IN;

  while(true) {

    unsigned int index = 1;
    for(auto iter = slave_sockets.begin(); iter != slave_sockets.end(); iter++) {
      set[index].fd = *iter;
      set[index].events = POLL_IN;
      index++;
    }

    unsigned int set_size = 1 + slave_sockets.size();

    poll(set, set_size, -1);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < set_size; i++) {
      if(set[i].revents & POLL_IN) {
        if(i) {

          static char buffer[1024];

          // This line works as expected.
          // int recv_size = read(set[i].fd, buffer, 1024);

          // This line sends messages in infinite loop?
          // I'm checking this with `telnet 127.0.0.1 12345`
          int recv_size = recv(set[i].fd, buffer, 1024, SO_NOSIGPIPE);

          if ((recv_size == 0) && (errno != EAGAIN)) {
            shutdown(set[i].fd, SHUT_RDWR);
            close(set[i].fd);
            slave_sockets.erase(set[i].fd);
          } else if(recv_size > 0) {
            send(set[i].fd, buffer, recv_size, SO_NOSIGPIPE);
          }
        } else {
          int slave_socket = accept(master_socket, 0, 0);
          set_nonblock(slave_socket);
          slave_sockets.insert(slave_socket);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This program is a basic echo server written in C++11 (but it's more like plain old C).

Behaviour I observe on Linux: Application starts, accepts client socket (I'm using `telnet 127.0.0.1 12345`), I write `"ping"`, press RET and get only one "ping" back.

Linux specs:

1) `clang++ -v`

```
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

2) `uname -a`

```
Linux julian-dell 4.4.0-112-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 11:48:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Behaviour I observe on OS X: Application starts, accepts client socket, I write "ping", press RET and get infinite amount of `"pings"` back. The only way to make `poll` block on OS X is to use `read` instead of `recv` to read from `socket`.

OS X specs:

1) `clang++ -v`

```
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

2) `uname -a`

```
Darwin Julians-MacBook-Pro.local 17.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.3.0: Thu Nov  9 18:09:22 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.31.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

My question is: Is it a bug, intended behaviour on OS X (also BSD?) or I just made a mistake in my code, which is somehow ignored by Linux? And I don't completely understand how changing `recv` to `read` affects `poll` behaviour - aren't they the same system call.

Comment: `if ((recv_size == 0) && (errno != EAGAIN))` makes no sense. `errno` is only valid immediately after an error has occurred, and `recv` returns `-1` on error, not `0`.

Comment: What is `SO_NOSIGPIPE`? I don't see it in the list of valid `recv` flags, and it wouldn't make sense anyway: `SIGPIPE` is generated by writing to a pipe/socket, not reading from it.

Comment: What's the point of doing `shutdown` before `close`?

Comment: @melpomene I thought that `SO_NOSIGPIPE` is an OS X version of `MSG_NOSIGNAL`, my bad. It does not make any sense to perform shutdown before `close`, yeah.  `if ((recv_size == 0) && (errno != EAGAIN))` here I mean "we wasn't able to read any data, but we are asked to try to read it again" and errno will be valid here as I can see, no?

Comment: If `recv_size == 0`, then no error occurred, and `errno` does not have a meaningful value. You can only check `errno` if `recv` returned `-1`.

Comment: @melpomene, Hmm, you are right. +1 mistake in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO_NOSIGPIPE is a [socket option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsockopt.html)
 not intended to be passed to the `recv()` family of functions.

On your OS X installation, SO_NOSIGPIPE sets the same bit as MSG_PEEK would, which means your `recv()` call is not actually draining the socket's data buffer but instead just "peeking" at available data.  Thus the data remains behind the socket, which of course then polls readable indefinitely.

(Presumably you intended to set MSG_NOSIGNAL, but, as [@melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) points out in comments, this behavior pertains to *sending* data on sockets, not receiving it.)

Comment: Hah, I was just about to post this. `SO_NOSIGPIPE` is `0x1022`, which (in `recv`/`send` options) corresponds to `MSG_SEND | MSG_CTRUNC | MSG_PEEK` (`0x1000 | 0x20 | 0x2`).

Comment: @pilcrow, as I understood MSG_NOSIGNAL does not exists on OS X. What should I use instead? or OS X does not need anything like MSG_NOSIGNAL?

Comment: @raventid, a `recv` does not need MSG_NOSIGNAL, Linux, OS X, or otherwise.

Comment: @pilcrow yep, got this. But for the `send` it's needed, right?

Comment: @raventid, I don't mean to be evasive but that depends — what's your design?  What are you doing with SIGPIPE/EPIPE?  Etc.  Might be best as a separate question if/when you have problems.